# Create and populate columns from key values in another column

Tags: r, reshape

I'm pulling data from a database into R.  I end up with a data frame containing three data series (A,B,C).  It looks something like this:

```
month       series  value
2012-12     A       10.45
2012-11     A       11.20
2012-10     A       11.04
2012-12     B       8.24
2012-11     B       8.89
2012-10     B       9.74
2012-12     C       25.01
2012-11     C       29.87
2012-10     C       26.74
```

I'm trying to chart the three series on a line chart.  I think the easiest way to do that would be to put it in a format like this:

```
month       A       B       C
2012-12     10.45   8.24    25.01
2012-11     11.20   8.89    29.87
2012-10     11.04   9.74    26.74
```

Is there a slick way to do this?

Comment: This is called going from long to wide format - there are piles of examples on SO, you just need to know what to search for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r

Answer (score 1):

You can change the format using the `reshape` function.  Or with more flexibility the reshape2 package.

However, with the original long format that you have you can plot the data, probably easiest will be with the ggplot2 or lattice packages.